# Java blocking local applet from running

Tags: java

does anyone know a way to enable java to run my local applet?
I work on OS X with Java 8 update 71 so my java security settings go only from HIGH to VERY HIGH.
I don't know how to add a LOCAL FILE to exception. It doesn't accept it.

This is just an Applet where I have the html page that links to my java class and I run it without any IDE, but just the web browser. I mean it's not any complex program that needs me JSP and those sort of things.

Comment: Are you using some web container? Like Tomcat or jetty. Or perhaps full application server like Glassfish or jBoss or what ever?

Comment: I use GlassFish when using java-ee applications, but this is just an applet. I just added some details to the main question.

Comment: An applet is NOT a web application. An applet MUST run within a web server or appletviewer or it will be denied to run.

Comment: How do I do that? I have GlassFish, but how do I run it from there?